# Is the following set necessarily closed

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S$ be any set and define $V = \{ t \in \mathbb{R}: |t - s| \leq 1 \text{ for some }s \in S\}$. Is $V$ necessarily closed?

My instinct told me that it shouldn't be, but I fail to find a counterexample... Any hint or idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you wrote "Let $S$ be any set", we would have to construe it as "Let $S$ be any set **of real numbers**" if this is to make sense.

Suppose $S= (0,1)$.  Then $\{t\in\mathbb R : |s-t|\le 1\} = (-1,2)$, and that is not closed.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S = (0,1)$, then $V = (-1, 2)$ is not closed.